# How to display db stored questions, that allows individual answers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, loops

I have a table with a couple hundred questions, Question(id, QuestionText).  I have not yet totally figured out the answer tables but probably something like:  a User_Answer table, User_Answer(id, personid, questionid, answer_type, answer), and an answer table, Answer_Type(id, type).  The types are 'yes/no', numeric, text.

I have the query set up to grab the questions I need, depending on the page, but I am having some trouble with the coding in the view.  Currently I have:

```
            foreach (var item in Model) {
                <div class="question-label">
                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionText)
                </div>
                <div class="question-field">
                       @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelitem => item.Answer, "Yes") Yes
                       @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelitem => item.Answer, "No") No
                </div>
            }
```

The questions display great, but in this case, the radio buttons think they are all in one set.  This page has 12 questions on it and although I get a seperate yes/no pair of buttons for each question, I can only select one yes or no for the whole page.  Do I need to set up an array maybe, so I can loop through with a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop with an index instead. `RadioButtonFor` is outputting the same name/id for all items.

So your razor may look like:

```
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelitem => Model[i].Answer, "Yes") Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each set of radio buttons the same name. That should fix it.

Just be careful what names you give them, because they'll have to match your model (but that's another story!).

Edit-see Doogie's answer, it addresses both.